# send coordinates to mysql with updates

Tags: xamarin

I want to send user longitude and latitude to mysql database and display markers on map, when user open app his location updates automatically, Iam Using xamarin and I am not found any suitable solution. can anyone give me step by step example

Comment: You shouldn't expose your database to the public internet. Instead create a webservice that can be used by your app. How to create a webservice in c# and use it with Xamarin is well documented on Google.

Comment: there are a number of sample apps and articles that will show you how to a) use the GPS, b) use a db, c) plot markers on a map.  Can you be more specific about what you're having trouble with?   Nobody is going to write an entire app demonstrating how to make all of those pieces work together just to answer your question.

Comment: thank you. firstly Iam new in xamarin , secondly I want to use a webservices with php mysql to store users coordinates in mysql database in first app, and get those coordinate and display it on map with markers in second app, also when user change his location the server must update his location

Comment: I am using this tutorial to fetch coordinates from mysql http://www.androidcodec.com/xamarin-mysql-coordinates-map-android, but I want another one to store coordinates in database and when user open the app his location updated auto